# ProgrammingError: permission denied for relation postgres and django

Tags: sql, linux, django, database, postgresql

This is what i have done

1. I have configured django website on a linux server recently with a `root` user unfortunately
2. Now i have created a normal user on linux server and moved the entire website to new user(`adam`)

I expect i have configured the postgres database when i am in root

But after moving to new user, i can't access some of my database tables and keep on getting the below error

```
ProgrammingError: permission denied for relation geoapp_zipcodes_us
```

Below are my django database settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'USER': 'adam',
        'NAME': 'client',
        'PASSWORD': 'client',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

*Note: The database id geo django spatial and very huge in gb's, so can'delete or recreate in this stage*

I googled some posts and tried the below steps but din't worked out

```
client=> GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO adam;
ERROR:  role "adam" does not exist
```

Can anyone please let me know how to remove the above `permission denied for relation` error ?

Comment: This is very strange. If user `adam` does not exist, how can Django be connecting to the database as `adam`? Anyway, you can create it with `CREATE USER adam;`

Comment: Yes we can create, but if we create a database user `adam`, does that relates to linux user `adam` ? sorry i was not best at database user stuff

Comment: No, database users and operating system users are completely different. If you have a database user `adam` and an operating system user `adam`, the two are completely unrelated.

Comment: ok then how do i clear the above permission error ? i am facing this after i moved/configured the complete code base from root user to normal(adam) user